# Nop commerce - Using Transaction concept to save changes or Rollback changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, nopcommerce

I am trying to add shipment and shipment items to database and I want to commit those changes to database only when all the shipment items are added. Due to any application failure, if any one of my shipment items doesn't get added, I want to rollback the changes. So for this I am trying to use transactions concept. I just want to know whether there is any implementation for Transactions in the EF code for NOP Commerce application that I can use.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you're making your operations in a single SaveChanges with a new context (meaning you have done a `new MyContext()` just before), there's no need to do any more code. SaveChanges already implements a transactional behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No into nopcommerce there is not any code/implementation for transactions.

For that you can create your own dbcontext.

Comment: Yup Got it. Thanks!